# Regular expression any characters in a-z, 0-9, #, +, -,

Tags: .net, regex

How do I match a string containing a-z, 0-9, #, +, - & a period, in any order? No other characters.

Comment: Why this down vote? Please tell me. I have done lot of research for few hours and couldn't learn in short time. So I wanted help. Members who support me, please up vote.

Comment: Your question is not clear and does not show any research effort. 1) You do not show any examples of valid or invalid strings. 2) You have not shown what you have tried. 3) You haven't shown why that failed to work. 4) Your use of `&` instead of the word "and" is confusing. 5) You probably mean "or" instead of "and" anyway. 6) You haven't clearly specified whether you do or don't want upper case letters. 7) You haven't said if this will be used with `Regex.Match`, `RegexValidator` or something else. 8) etc...etc... I didn't downvote you, but I can understand why many people did.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
^[a-z0-9#+.-]+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` is a start of string [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).
- `[...]` is a character class.
- `+` means "one or more".
- `$` is an end of string anchor.

Comment: @Ωmega: Please read the question carefully. He means "containing a-z **,** 0-9 **,** # **,** + **,** - **and** a period". The `,` and `&` are list separators and not the characters he wants to select. Consider "He ate bread, butter **and** jam". This means: He ate "bread". He ate "butter". He ate "jam". It does not mean: He ate "and". Also consider "A, B, C & D". The `&` is not an element of the list. It is a separator. It is like a comma except it is used between the last and next-last element. Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma

Answer (score 0):

use this regex:

```
^[\da-z#+.&-]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] myStrings = { "1-2&3-4",
                             "ABC#123", 
                             "12+abc-34#" };
      string pattern = @"^[a-z0-9&#+.-]+$";
      foreach (string myString in myStrings)
         Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} a valid string.", 
                           myString, 
                           Regex.IsMatch(myString, pattern) ? "is" : "is not");
   }
}
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/eFbpc).

Comment: `\d` is unicode based in .net, so "1-2&3-4١" is a valid string with your expression. (Note the "١" in the string, an "arabic" digit)